# What is the behaviour of a RestTemplate when multiple ClientHttpRequestInterceptors are registered?

Tags: java, spring, resttemplate

Imagine I have the following the following 2 `ClientHttpRequestInterceptor`s:

```java
public class RequestLoggerInterceptor implements ClientHttpRequestInterceptor {
  @Override
  public ClientHttpResponse intercept(HttpRequest httpRequest, byte[] bytes, ClientHttpRequestExecution clientHttpRequestExecution) throws IOException {
    log.info("HTTP request: {}", httpRequest);
    return clientHttpRequestExecution.execute(httpRequest, bytes);
  }
}
```

```java
public class ResponseLoggerInterceptor implements ClientHttpRequestInterceptor {
  @Override
  public ClientHttpResponse intercept(HttpRequest httpRequest, byte[] bytes, ClientHttpRequestExecution clientHttpRequestExecution) throws IOException {
    ClientHttpResponse response = clientHttpRequestExecution.execute(httpRequest, bytes);
    log.info("HTTP response: {}", response);
    return response
  }
}
```

And I add them both to the same `RestTemplate`:

```java
ClientHttpRequestInterceptor requestLogger = new RequestLoggerInterceptor();
ClientHttpRequestInterceptor responseLoggerr = new ResponseLoggerInterceptor();
RestTemplate template = new RestTemplate();
template.setInterceptors(Arrays.asList(requestLogger, responseLogger));
```

What will be the behaviour when a request is executed using this `RestTemplate`?

In both `ClientHttpRequestInterceptor`s, the `clientHttpRequestExecution.execute` method is called. Does this mean that the request is executed twice?

Comment: you could just run it and see that request executed once, no?

Comment: That's true, but most of the questions on this website can be 'just run to see what happens'. Do we want to force all users facing this issue to test this? Or will we allow them to find this question and get an instant answer and possible links to documentation?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the [documentation of ClientHttpRequestExecution](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/client/ClientHttpRequestExecution.html)

> Represents the context of a client-side HTTP request execution. Used
>   to invoke the **next interceptor** in the interceptor chain, or - if the
>   calling **interceptor is last** - **execute the request itself**.

Hence the request will not execute twice.
It will execute in following way,

1. start `clientHttpRequestExecution.execute`
2. call first interceptor `requestLogger.intercept`
3. call back `clientHttpRequestExecution.execute`
4. call second interceptor `responseLogger.intercept`
5. call back `clientHttpRequestExecution.execute`
6. no interceptor left, call actual `ClientHttpRequest.execute`

For more details, read [InterceptingClientHttpRequest](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-web/src/main/java/org/springframework/http/client/InterceptingClientHttpRequest.java#L90) `InterceptingRequestExecution.execute` method.

Comment: Ah, I see. I was under the impression that `clientHttpRequestExecution.execute` was going to perform a `http` request instead of calling the next `Interceptor`.

Comment: I was wondering what the the order of the Interceptors being run will be and then I saw that the it is `List` of interceptors. Hence, the order in which the interceptors is stored in the Interceptors list is the order in which it will be run.

Comment: @KarthikRao, this is true for spring on or before version 4.3.x. After spring 5.0.x, the run ordering may change, [see](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/client/support/InterceptingHttpAccessor.html#setInterceptors-java.util.List-)

Answer (score 7):

`RestTemplate` allows you to register multiple HTTP request interceptors by implementing the `ClientHttpRequestInterceptor`([doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/client/ClientHttpRequestInterceptor.html)) interface.
Every such interceptor is a **pass through** for the HTTP request, eventually executing the request after passing through all the interceptors.

The signature of the method to be implemented in the interceptor is

```
ClientHttpResponse intercept(HttpRequest request, byte[] body, ClientHttpRequestExecution execution) throws IOException;
```

where the implementation of the [execute](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-web/src/main/java/org/springframework/http/client/InterceptingClientHttpRequest.java#L90) method of `ClientHttpRequestExecution`([doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/client/ClientHttpRequestExecution.html)) interface takes care of **passing the request to the next interceptor or executing the request
if there are no more interceptors left to be intercepted by**.

Since **Spring 5.0.x**, interceptors are [sorted](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/5.0.x/spring-web/src/main/java/org/springframework/http/client/support/InterceptingHttpAccessor.java#L64) by Spring using `AnnotationAwareOrderComparator`([doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/annotation/AnnotationAwareOrderComparator.html))
and hence the sorting can be defined with `@Order` or `@Priority` too. So if you are in the said Spring version and you annotate the interceptors as below

```
@Order(1)
public class ResponseLoggerInterceptor implements ClientHttpRequestInterceptor {
...
}

@Order(2)
public class RequestLoggerInterceptor implements ClientHttpRequestInterceptor {
...
}
```

the request will first be intercepted by `ResponseLoggerInterceptor` and then by `RequestLoggerInterceptor`.

So in your case, the request will be intercepted by `RequestLoggerInterceptor` and `ResponseLoggerInterceptor` according to the sorted order and then finally executed. **The request will be executed only once**.

**Note:**
RestTemplate will be [deprecated](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web.html#webmvc-resttemplate) in a future version and Spring suggests users to use [WebClient](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web.html#webmvc-webclient) instead of RestTemplate from version 5.0 onwards.

Answer (score 2):

No, the request is only executed once at the end. When you set the interceptors in the rest template the underlying `ClientHttpRequestFactory` is wrapped as `InterceptingclientHttpRequestFactory` with interceptors.

When you made the request using rest template the request is read by interceptors followed by request execution and the response is processed by interceptors. That is all done using `ClientHttpRequestExecution`.